# Is there a way to change domain name on GeoLocation prompt message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

Is there a way to change domain name on GeoLocation prompt message? 
So I have a web widget plugin that is hosted on one of my server. It has a geolocation attached to it and I am using html5 `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` . I have my widget installed on one of my clients website. When I open it, it prompt to allow geo-location which works perfectly. However the prompt was pointing to my domain like "Would you like to share your location with [mydomain.com]". I wanted it so that the domain name for the prompt message will be on my client website. How would I do that? Is that even possible?

Best regards,

Comment: How is that "web widget plugin" loaded into the client site?

Comment: This is a security feature. If you could set the domain name you could also trick people that the request is actually genuine even though it comes from some advertiser... That said, you'll have to deploy the script on your clients server to get the right domain string displayed.